# Python multiprocessing Queue failure

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I create 100 child processes

```
proc_list = [
    Process(target = simulator, args=(result_queue,))
    for i in xrange(100)]
```

and start them

```
for proc in proc_list: proc.start()
```

Each process puts into the result_queue (instance of multiprocessing.Queue) 10000 tuples after doing some processing.

```
def simulate(alg_instance, image_ids, gamma, results,
                     simulations, sim_semaphore):
  (rs, qs, t_us) =  alg_instance.simulate_multiple(image_ids, gamma,
                                             simulations)
  all_tuples = zip(rs, qs, t_us)
  for result in all_tuples:
    results.put(result)
  sim_semaphore.release()
```

I should be (?) getting 1000000 tuples at the queue, but after various runs I get these (sample) sizes:
14912
19563
12952
13524
7487
18350
15986
11928
14281
14282
7317

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure ``simulate()`` actually returns 10,000 tuples?

Comment: Yes. Tested it extensively...

Comment: Are you joining each of the processes to make sure you are waiting for all of them to complete?

Comment: Naming a variable `tuple` is a very bad idea.  `tuple` is a basic type and you shouldn't replace it in your namespace with something else.

Comment: @K.Brafford I haven't really named them tuple -- just wrote the sketch of the function. I've updated the function code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My solution to multiprocessing issues is almost always to use the Manager objects. While the exposed interface is the same, the underlying implementation is much simpler and has less bugs.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
result_queue = manager.Queue()
```

Try it out and see if it doesn't fix your issues.

Comment: I started losing my nerves with multiprocessing.Queue, envisioned I must have made some mistake but no change really, just swapped it with manager.Queue and it started working flawlessly :\ -- thanks a bunch for advice

Answer (score 6):

The multiprocessing.Queue is said to be thread-safe in its documentations. But when you are doing inter-process communications with Queue, it should be used with multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

Answer (score 2):

There's no evidence from the OP post that `multiprocessing.Queue` does not work. The code posted by the OP is not at all sufficient to understand what's going on: do they join all the processes? do they correctly pass the queue to the child processes (has to be as a parameter if it's on Windows)? do their child processes verify that they actually got 10000 tuples? etc.

There's a chance that the OP is really encountering a hard-to-reproduce bug in `mp.Queue`, but given the amount of testing CPython has gone through, and the fact that I just ran 100 processes x 10000 results without any trouble, I suspect the OP actually had some problem in their own code.

Yes, `Manager().Queue()` mentioned in other answers is a perfectly fine way to share data, but there's no reason to avoid `multiprocessing.Queue()` based on unconfirmed reports that "something is wrong with it".